# Como saber si dos cadenas son amigas en java?

Tags: java, string

se dice que dos cadenas S y T son amigas si existe dos cadenas no vacias u y v tales que S =uv y T=vu por ejemplo, "tokyo" y " kyoto" son amigas, siendo u="to" y v= "kyo".

ESCRIBA UN PROGRAMA EN JAVA QUE RECIBA COMO ENTADA DOS CADENAS S Y T, E IMPRIMA SI S Y T SON AMIGAS.

Hola por favor ayuden es una ejerció que me dejaron en la universidad y no he podido realizar, he intentado con un ciclo for para guardar los carácter en una variable , pero no he podido

```
public class CadenasAmigas {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "TOKYO";
    String t = "KYOTO";

    //int y = s.length();
    //int g = t.length();


   for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++) {
       char can =s.charAt(i);
       String cnd3 = String.valueOf(can);


       for (int j = 0;j<t.length(); j++) {
           char dft =t.charAt(j);
           String can4 = String.valueOf(dft);
           

       }

   }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorre la primera cadena `S` y sepárala en dos trozos, `u` y `v` justo como te dice la definición. Si `v + u` == `T` entonces son amigas. Si se recorrió la cadena y no se encontró coincidencias, no son amigas.

El programa completo quedaría:

```
public class CadenasAmigas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "PATOS";
        String t = "SPATO";

        if (sonAmigas( s, t )) {
            System.out.printf( "Las cadenas '%s' y '%s' son amigas", s, t );
        } else {
            System.out.printf( "Las cadenas '%s' y '%s' NO son amigas", s, t );
        }
    }


    public static boolean sonAmigas(String S, String T) {
        if (S.length() != T.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < S.length(); i++) {
            String u = S.substring( 0, i );
            String v = S.substring( i );

            if (T.equals( v + u )) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Puedes ejecutarlo online en [este enlace](https://onlinegdb.com/d4xZmyb14).

Comment: muchas gracias Jaime Menéndez , atendiendo la lógica tu algoritmo, tenia una idea similar para desarrollarlo pero no se que que estoy fallando si es la lógica o en manejo de la implementacion en  java.